# getting error bad URI when putting facebook access token on the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

This is the error i get:

```
Bad Request

bad URI `/v1/user/authenticate.json?access_key=1443560867|2.AQBCC2jMKOEzSjnO.3600.1312826400.0-1129666978|VttMJncSU17Br-g38R9eGF5_qCQ'.
```

The authenticate method:

```
require 'open-uri'

class UserController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def authenticate

    file = open(URI.encode("https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=" + params[:access_key]))

    facebook = JSON.parse(file.read)

    if facebook["data"].present?
      @result = "200"
    else
      @result = "403"
    end

    respond_with(@result)

  end

end
```

EDIT: SOLVED THE CODE WORKS ON HEROKU... THE PROBLEM IS ON THE LOCALHOST:3000

Answer (score 2):

On Webrick server, simply add following to config/environments/development.rb:

```
# Allow webrick to accept pipe char in query string
URI::DEFAULT_PARSER = URI::Parser.new(:UNRESERVED => URI::REGEXP::PATTERN::UNRESERVED + '|')
```